# Class constructor NgbDatepickerConfig cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, ngb-datepicker

After updating to Angular 13 and ng-bootstrap to v11.0.0 (as stated [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap) one should use v11.0.0 for Angular 13 and bootstrap 4) I get the following error in jest(v27.5) tests:

```
TypeError: Class constructor NgbDatepickerConfig cannot be invoked without 'new'

       5 | export class DefaultDatepickerConfig extends NgbDatepickerConfig {
       6 |   constructor() {
    >  7 |     super();
         |     ^
```

Tried to use 11.0.0-rc.0 - didn't helped. Got another error.

Any thoughts on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no answers here so I'm going to answer my own question.

So I've found a fix for this problem. Changing `"compilerOptions": { "target": "es5"}` to `es2015` in my `tsconfig.json` file helped. It solved the problem immediately